# Why does Google Chrome not close completely?

Tags: google-chrome

I installed Google Chrome for flash capability. 
When I try to close it, it appears to close correctly, but two of the three processes in System Monitor remain open. 
This should not happen. 
And if Chrome is sending information back to Google while the browser is closed, I should know about it.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the names, or a screen shot with the names of the processes still running in background.

Comment: Could you add a list of plugins/extensions you have installed?

Comment: The question is clear enough if reader know about this issue and can answer for it. There is no clear question if the reader does not know about the problem.

Comment: Anyway, Current version of gnome desktop on Ubuntu 17.10 seems not send SIGTERM to remind apps so if I just closed chrome and logged out, then the status of chrome become uncleanly terminated.

Answer (score 5):

You have to set in the settings

*'Settings'* > *'Advanced'* > Under *'System'* untick *"Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed"*

Help page [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1184722)

I think there is something else you may have to disable, search for "`Background`" in settings to see if there is anything.